# How can I Deconstruct Value Tuples that are out parameters in C# 7?

Tags: c#, .net, value-type, c#-7.0

Given the following:

```
var dic = new Dictionary<string, (int, int)>()
{
    ["A"] = (1, 2)
};

dic.TryGetValue("A", out (int, int) value);
```

I can easily get the `value` out of the dictionary, but how can I deconstruct it to get each individual values so something like this:

```
dic.TryGetValue("A", out var (left, right));
```

Comment: Can we assume that you know the amount of items in the tuple and their types, or are you asking for a solution that can unwrap _any_ tuple?

Comment: Yes you can make such assumptions.

Comment: If you know that Item1 is left and Item2 is right, why use a Tuple?  Use a class that is more descriptive.

Comment: @ErikPhilips And increase our heap allocation and memory usage 10 fold? I think I will stick to Value Tuples; You could have at least suggested a `struct`!

Comment: Unless you actually have a memory problem, you're actually creating a maintainability problem for nothing.

Comment: We wouldn't have gone via this route had we not carefully profiled the app. I am tired of people on SO jumping to conclusions without knowing the context instead of trying to answer a very specific question.

Comment: @ErikPhilips these tuples aren't the old Tuple. They *are* useful, they *can* make things more maintainable and improve performance. They *are* structs, which means no garbage collection. As for `unless you actually have a memory problem` there's a *huge* amount of work going on to reduce allocations in .NET, packages, algorithms right now. If you have a web application with even moderate traffic, you do care about GC freezes

Comment: @MaYaN unfortunately SO has become full of "specific questions" that are extremely bad. It's become so bad that out of 10 questions one might look at, 9 are bad or duplicate. In this case though it's a case of unfamiliarity with the scenario.

Comment: @MaYaN you should probably consider installing Update 4 which adds C# 7.1 support. This adds tuple name inferencing which can make code that uses tuples a bit cleaner

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> `dic.TryGetValue("A", out var (left, right));`

This syntax is not yet supported, it *may* be added in future. [reference](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/611)

---

You can give tuple elements name like this.

```
if(dic.TryGetValue("A", out (int left, int right) t))
{
    var (left, right) = (t.left, t.right);

    // use (left, right) or directly use (t.left, t.right)
}
```

I couldn't think of shorter syntax, Its just matter of time. c#7 is evolving faster than before so you just have to wait.

Comment: You could shorten it a bit with `out var t` then decompose it with `var (left,right)=t;`

Comment: Right, i missed that

Comment: With the new pattern syntax, you could do `TryGetValue("A", out var t) && t is var (left, right)`

Comment: @MarkusJarderot, I like your hack, but just a note that if you're testing `!TryGetValue` (when it's not there) you're unable to deconstruct since the `&&` predicate won't be evaluated and `left` and `right` will be considered uninitialized.  Kind of a bummer.

Comment: @KirkWoll have you tried using single &?

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary oh yeah, what an excellent point; I hadn't thought of that.